# How to put an arraylist from another class to a 2d arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, file-handling

```java
public void filehandling() throws IOException {
    FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\PCB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Billing\\src\\Files\\MeterNumber.txt");
    BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(f);
    b.write("13920");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("32981");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("2399");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("12903");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("59942");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("58342");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("12324");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("66342");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("90012");
    b.newLine();
    b.write("55221");
    b.close();
    f.close();
}

public void filetoarray() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\PCB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Billing\\src\\Files\\MeterNumber.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> mnumber = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        mnumber.add(line);
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    bufReader.close();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mdetails = new ArrayList();
    {
        ArrayList<String> ccode = new ArrayList();
        {
            ccode.add("123468");
            ccode.add("492312");
            ccode.add("642344");
            ccode.add("353421");
            ccode.add("354332");
            ccode.add("6746643");
            ccode.add("7578885");
            ccode.add("3949390");
            ccode.add("1000348");
            ccode.add("5396978");
            ccode.add("1234567");
        }

        ArrayList<String> prreading = new ArrayList();
        {
            prreading.add("1000");
            prreading.add("6000");
            prreading.add("3980");
            prreading.add("2300");
            prreading.add("4200");
            prreading.add("8000");
            prreading.add("1230");
            prreading.add("4222");
            prreading.add("5100");
            prreading.add("3000");
            prreading.add("");
        }

        ArrayList<String> ctype = new ArrayList();
        {
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("c");
            ctype.add("c");
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("c");
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("c");
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("r");
            ctype.add("");
        }

        mdetails.add(mnumber);
        mdetails.add(ccode);
        mdetails.add(prreading);
        mdetails.add(ctype);
    }
}
```

I was trying to use to convert a text file to arraylist then include it to a 2d arraylist from another class. I would like to add it to the 2d arraylist so I can simply just call on its contents using operations meant for 2d arraylists

I am quite new to java and haven't really found a solution to this and would greatly appreciate the help.

[This is how I plan to use the contents of the text file through array lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU7qd.png)

Comment: Hi , Can you please add sample input text file and sample output you are expecting?

Comment: Firstly, you could halve the length of stretches of your code by using a `PrintWriter` and just calling `pw.println("293847");` etc.
More importantly, we don't do "2d array lists". Java is an object-oriented language so you would have a `List` of objects encapsulating the data you want. It's difficult to see what you want here from your code, so you need to explain more

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. The basic idea behind my code is that I will put the contents of the text files into array lists and which will then be called on to display in a jframe.

Comment: Still too vague. What's in the text files and what is represented?

Comment: the numbers in the text file is the meter number. The user will input a 5 digit meter number and the program will find the corresponding 5 digit numbers and then retrieve information based on which meter number combination was met. The program I made is supposed to resemble a simple electric billing system.

Comment: OK, so you'd probably need at minimum `class Meter { private int id; private List<Integer> readings }` though for completeness each reading should have a date

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted your code to return a `List<List<String>>`.

Consider the following methods.

You don't need the `BufferedWriter` if you're just added a few lines.
Place your `FileWriter` into a try-with-resources block, so it will automatically close upon error.
Additionally, you can utilize the `append` method, which is a "builder" method, allowing you to chain calls.  You could also use `PrintWriter`, which has a `println` method, if you wanted, to make it a single call.

```java
public void filehandling(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path)) {
        String newline = System.lineSeparator();
        writer.append("13920").append(newline);
        writer.append("32981").append(newline);
        writer.append("2399").append(newline);
        writer.append("12903").append(newline);
        writer.append("59942").append(newline);
        writer.append("58342").append(newline);
        writer.append("12324").append(newline);
        writer.append("66342").append(newline);
        writer.append("90012").append(newline);
        writer.append("55221");
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

Similarly, place your `BufferedReader` within a try-with-resources block.
Utilize some additional methods to return your `ccode`, `prreading`, and `ctype` values.
It is of course not necessary, although it can improve the scalability of your application.
Finally, your declaring type, for an `ArrayList`, can just be `List`.

```java
public List<List<String>> filetoarray(String path) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line);
    }
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(lines);
    list.add(List.of(ccode()));
    list.add(List.of(prreading()));
    list.add(List.of(ctype()));
    return list;
}

String[] ccode() {
    return new String[] {
        "123468",
        "492312",
        "642344",
        "353421",
        "354332",
        "6746643",
        "7578885",
        "3949390",
        "1000348",
        "5396978",
        "1234567",
    };
}

String[] prreading() {
    return new String[] {
        "1000",
        "6000",
        "3980",
        "2300",
        "4200",
        "8000",
        "1230",
        "4222",
        "5100",
        "3000",
        ""
    };
}

String[] ctype() {
    return new String[] {
        "r",
        "r",
        "c",
        "c",
        "r",
        "c",
        "r",
        "c",
        "r",
        "r",
        ""
    };
}
```